# Work on Android Studio 3.0 project on 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've been working on an android app in Android Studio 3.0 canary 6 on another computer and using Github so that I can work on the project from any computer. Unfortunately, 3.0 doesn't scale correctly on my Surface Pro 4, so it is unusable. When I load the project in 2.3, I get an error that says something along the lines of "this gradle version requires Studio 3.0". I have tried tinkering with the gradle version in 2.3, but to no avail. Is it at all possible to totally convert the project for use in 2.3 (permanently; I would have no need to use 3.o again. I was just playing around with it.), and if so, how would I go about doing that? Thank you!

Comment: Try to `import` the project instead of `open`-ing it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

From 3.0 to 2.3.3 you must do the following changes:

Open your project on the Android Studio 2.3.

Expand Gradle Scripts, open gradle-wrapper.properties file and change the final piece of distributionUrl attribute to /gradle-3.3-all.zip . This may vary depending on your 2.x version.

Next, open build.gradle(Project: YOURPROJECT) and change the classpath inside dependencies {} to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' . In repositories {} that is inside buildscript {} change google() to  maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/' name 'Google' }. You should do this same thing to allprojects {} that is found just below dependencies {}.

Finally, open build.gradle(Module: app) and inside dependencies {} change the word "implementation" to "compile". Now sync your Gradle.

These changes will make the error you found, regarding the IDE version, to stop showing. You'll probably have other errors popping up that are related to sdk and dependencies versions. Just adjust the versioning of the sdk and dependencies to the ones that are used by your Android Studio 2.3. Some XML files may also show errors and you must manually correct those.